# Julia - using dictionary key as index for a multidimensional array

Tags: julia

I have a dictionary with keys as shown:

```
testdict = Dict{Array{Int64,1},Float64}([1,3,1] => 0.0, [2,3,1] => 0.0, [1,3,2] => 0.0, [2,3,2] => -2.64899e-16, [2,1,2] => 0.858307, [1,2,1] => 0.0, [1,2,2] => 0.0, [2,2,1] => 0.0, [2,2,2] => 0.65796, [2,1,1] => -5.81556e-16, [1,1,2] => -3.50541e-16, [1,1,1] => 0.0)
```

These keys vary considerably both regarding range and length, they are initialized by an array in the beginning of the function Im writing...it could look like

```
[2,3,2]
```

for the dictionary above...,

or

```
[10,3,50,60]
```

creating a dictionary with keys

```
[1,1,1,1], [1,1,1,12] ... , [10, 3, 50, 59], [10,3, 50, 60]
```

And what I need to accomplish, is create a multidimensional array by

```
result_array = Array(Float64, tuple([2,3,2])
```

But then I need to populate the array with the values from the dictionary, 
so I would need to set element [1,1,1] as

```
result_array[1,1,1] = 0.0
```

How can I use the keys from the dictionary to set the indices of the `result_array` with their respected values?

Comment: Rather than allocating an array for each index-key, you'd be far better off using a CartesianIndex. See http://julialang.org/blog/2016/02/iteration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Splat the key to turn `result_array[[1,1,1]...]` into `result_array[1,1,1]`.

```
testdict = Dict{Array{Int64,1},Float64}([1,3,1] => 0.0, [2,3,1] => 0.0, [1,3,2] => 0.0, [2,3,2] => -2.64899e-16, [2,1,2] => 0.858307, [1,2,1] => 0.0, [1,2,2] => 0.0, [2,2,1] => 0.0, [2,2,2] => 0.65796, [2,1,1] => -5.81556e-16, [1,1,2] => -3.50541e-16, [1,1,1] => 0.0)

result_array = Array(Float64,2,3,2)

for (k,v) in testdict
  result_array[k...] = testdict[k]
end
```

Comment: To automate size calculation: `result_array = Array(Float64,map(maximum,zip(keys(testdict)...))...)`

Comment: In the latest versions of Julia, creating the array like that would no longer work. One can use this instead: `result_array = Array{Float64}(undef, 2, 3, 2)`